# Manipulating tables in mysql by command line

Tags: mysql

I need to manipulate tables in my databases. I found this tutorial on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) which is great but it deals with only manipulating data inside one table, but what I need is tutorial for manipulating tables and not data inside them.

Here is what I mean by manipulating tables:

1. Delete all tables that begin with certain prefix
2. Move all tables that begins with certain prefix from one database to another
3. You can edit this list (and accordingly the list in accepted answer) so we can make this good learning resource.

Note: I did do research job before posting this question, and by seeing how we lack on these tutorials I decided to post it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use SQL to write the next query for example

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('DROP ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name)) 
FROM
  information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'database' 
  AND table_name LIKE 'prefix%'
```

That should generate a correct drop table string.

You can do a similar thing with rename table.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('database.',table_name, ' TO new.', table_name))) 
FROM
  information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'database' 
  AND table_name LIKE 'prefix%'
```

Older versions of MySQL may need you to run this first

```
 SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=9999999999;
```

or some other large number